# html input in razor view i have id and name attributes with them how to get their value in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, model-binding, dynamic-controls

Previously I was using `@html.EditorFor(model=>model.Degree_name)` but now I want to create dynamic forms as many times as the user clicks on add more button. So, I did that using html input controls and using javascript now my issue is I want to get the values which I insert into these textboxes in my controller. Previously I was passing model object in my controller which was working fine but now as my input controls are not model binded so how to get their values in controller using model object?

Previous code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.educations.School, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Enter School Name", @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.educations.School, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

New Code:

```
<input  name="School" id="School" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter School Name" class="form-control" />
```

My controller method is below:

```
public ActionResult Create(Registration registration, HttpPostedFileBase upload,FacultyViewModel vm)
```

`facultyViewModel` was getting values previously.

Answer (score 1):

From what it sounds you want to get a list of your model FacultyViewModel as a parameter. Change controller method signature to one below so vm is a collection of FacultyViewModels.

Controller

```
public ActionResult create(Registration registration, HttpPostedFileBase upload,
                           List<FacultyViewModel> vm) 
{    

}
```

To have list of models passed to the controller parameter the html needs to look like this where every time you click add it adds the input tags with incremented index in name attribute.

```
<input name="FacultyViewModel[0].educations.School" type="text" />
<input name="FacultyViewModel[0].educations.Degree_Title" type="text"/>

<input name="FacultyViewModel[1].educations.School" type="text" />
<input name="FacultyViewModel[1].educations.Degree_Title" type="text" />

<input name="FacultyViewModel[2].educations.School" type="text" />
<input name="FacultyViewModel[2].educations.Degree_Title" type="text" />
```

Tested with what everything below.

Controller

```
public ActionResult postTest(List<Test> test)
{
    //I set break point here to view list contents
}
```

cshtml

```
<div class="container pt-5">
<div class="pt-5">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("postTest", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myForm", @id = "CreatePostForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="text" name="Test[0].school" />
        <input type="text" name="Test[0].degree" />


        <input type="text" name="Test[1].school" />
        <input type="text" name="Test[1].degree" />

        <div class="form-group pt-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Post</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Your class FacultyViewModel needs to have a parameterless constructor.

Test Class

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(string s, string d)
    {
        this.School = s;
        this.Degree = d;
    }

    public Test()
    {
    }

    public string School { get; set; }
    public string Degree { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: should i hard code vm[counter].educations.propertyName other than counter the rest of the things needed to be hard coded with name attribute?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IEnumerable<FacultyViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'educations' and no accessible extension method 'educations' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<FacultyViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) CMS_Monitoring_Student E:\CMS-Monitoring\CMS-Monitoring\Controllers\RegistrationsssController.cs 284 Active

Comment: @Tabor Yes that's what I would do. Also I edited my answer to fix some stuff in yours and show an example of what I tested with.